# mvn spring boot run from the parent module of a multi module project starts only the first project in the module. How to start both?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have say two spring boot projects naming-server and cloud-config. I have created the following parent pom.xml. When I run mvn spring-boot:run from the parent directory, only naming-server starts. Is there a way to start both naming-server and cloud-config together?

```
<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>multi-start</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>multi-start</name>
<description>start multiple projects</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>naming-server</module>
    <module>cloud-config</module>
</modules>
```

Pom.xml for cloud-config:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.cloud.config</groupId>
<artifactId>cloud-config</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cloud-config</name>
<description>Cloud configuration</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.M3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

pom for naming-server:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.eureka.naming</groupId>
<artifactId>naming-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>naming-server</name>
<description>Project to name servers</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Can you share the pom.xml for the modules as well?

Comment: sure, updated with pom.xml for both modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the spring-boot-maven-plugin should be applied to only one project of which you want to create an executable jar. It must be removed from the other modules. To tell Maven to not build an executable jar for the Library project, you must remove the following block from the pom.xml created by the Spring Initializr.

For more details, see https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/#initial

Just remove or comment out the block like following:

```
<!-- <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build> -->
```

Alternatively, you could specify parent of the modules within the pom file with  tag